# Why does my copy of Mix on OSX have an ancient version of Solidity?

Tags: solidity, mix, mac-osx

I just downloaded the latest version of Mix, and noticed it doesn't support inline assembly. Clicking on Mix -> About Mix, I see it's running version 0.2.2 of Solidity.

Why is it running such an old version, and is there any way to upgrade it short of building Mix myself from source?

Comment: which version of Mix are you using?

Comment: Isn't your question 'How to upgrade the version of solidity in OSX?'

Comment: @arodriguezdonaire 1.0.1, which I downloaded about a day ago.

Comment: @5chdn It's also "why is the latest version of Mix using such an ancient version of Solidity?"

Answer (score 2):

The DMG I found [here](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/index.html) installed Mix v1.0.1 as well.

[On the Mix releases page](https://github.com/ethereum/mix/releases), we see that version 1.0.1 was released on February 17, 2016.

[On the Solidity releases page](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases) we see that Solidity v0.2.2 was also released on February 17, 2016.

As of April 19, 2016 `Solidity is Version 0.3.2` and `Mix is Version 1.0.3.`

It seems like that disk image is out of date.

---

You could try installing via [Homebrew](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/osx-homebrew.html) using

brew update

brew upgrade

brew tap ethereum/ethereum

brew install cpp-ethereum --with-gui

brew linkapps cpp-ethereum

I tried but it took too long (I stopped after an hour or so) and I needed to get real work done. The warning on the Homebrew page is no joke: `that brew install on El Capitan machines triggers a (very slow) build from source.`

Unfortunately, it does seem like your best option is to build from source at this point.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to build from source. This way you will have fully up to date ethereum. And it's not so hard really. Here's the commands.

First get yo brew on

```
brew update
brew upgrade

brew install boost --c++11
brew install cmake cryptopp miniupnpc leveldb gmp jsoncpp libmicrohttpd libjson-rpc-cpp llvm37
brew install homebrew/versions/v8-315
brew install qt5 --with-d-bus //this takes a while (approx. 8 hours) use --verbose to see progress
```

once that's done, run this

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella.git
cd webthree-umbrella
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. 
make -j4 #j manipulates the cores...ie...up the number if you want it done faster
cd mix/build && open Mix-ide.app
```